# postman access token with custom domain

Tags: rest, authentication, postman, basic-authentication

I am working on a testing a rest api in postman. Our Organization has a production domain (let's say ABC) and a demo domain (ABCM). The authentication for the rest api requires basic auth with userid and password, but to test the rest api in DEMO environment, we need to pass the userid that is setup in demo domain ABCM. Usually when I test the rest api, I just provide my userid and password for basic auth without any domains. How do I specify the non-prod domain name in postman to get the access token. I have tried the below variants and they are not working.

`ABCM\{userid}`

`{userid}@ABCM.com`

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is the format to pass Basic Auth username and password in a URL.

```
https://{username}:{password}@abcm.com/
```

The authorization header of the request will be then set with a base-64 encoded token from the string `{username}:{password}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, I am confused. I am already having the URL of the REST API as the endpoint URL. How do I pass the basic auth info in the form of URL again? Is there an example that I have a look?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. From what I understood, you have an endpoint URL and you want to pass basic authentication information (username & password) to it. Am I correct?

Comment: How is the API deciding what domain to pass the authentication to?  It will be the API code that defines this and whether you need to add a domain name or not.  Including any potential formatting.  I would have thought that as you don't have to do this for the production domain,  you wouldn't need this for the demo domain either.  It would be the API that calls the domain controller for that domain under the hood.  All Postman really does is encode the details and add an Authorization header to the request.  Something like Authorization: "Basic aGVsbG86bXlsb3ZlbHk="

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. I was wrong in stating my post. The REST API needed to be called out with a bearer token and that bearer token must be obtained by calling out a OpenIDConnectAuth service with basic auth credentials. In our org, they deployed the OpenIDConnectAuth service in the ABCM domain (it has a different URL with abcm in it) and I had to use my ABCM domain account to make a callout to get the bearer token. Once I get the bearer token from this DEMO service, I was able to use it to make a callout to the original REST API.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me with this.